# How to clean gas stove top

Tags: cleaning, stove

Can someone tell me if there is any way I can clean up these spots on gas stove top around burners ? It is from cooking. We have tried vinegar, baking soda, dish wash , no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: to me that looks like places where the enamel finish has bubbled up.

Comment: Looks like elbow grease is missing from your list.

Comment: @SolarMike neither accurate nor helpful.     FWIW I agree that it looks like degraded enamel finish.